# Controlling XAML grid structire using VisualStateManager

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, grid-layout

I am writing a WinRT app and need to change its layout in a snapped view. In a regular view details are displayed in grid of a following structure:

MainGrid: contains 2 rows, 2 columns (let's call them M11, M12, M21, M22)

DetailGrid: occupies rightmost column and upper row of MainGrid, contains 1 row, 2 columns of equal, so the layout looks like this:
M12 contains D1 and D2 layered horizontally

In a snapped view I want DetailGrid to be redefined so it has a single column and 2 rows: 
M12 contains D1 and D2 layered vertically

If I didn't care about column width, I could use StackPanel instead of Grid to display details and simply change StackPanel orientation in a snapped mode from Horizontal to Vertical. But D1 and D2 must use all available space in a standard mode and have equal size, therefore I control them via Grid ColumnDefinition. But grid definition is not something that is easily controlled using VisualStateManager.

What do you think would be the best way to manage such layout?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the description its a little difficult to visualize, perhaps a quick image explanation from mspaint of what you're after could be more descriptive?

Comment: My I suggest: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/12/the-two-ways-to-handle-orientation-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Grid definitions are hard to control but I've found changing Grid.RowSpan or Grid.RowColumn span on the controls within the grid should be able to do what you need in snap view